# addPoint with HIGHCHARTS (xAxis dateTime)

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, socket.io

I based this tutorial to create a chart in real time.
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Then as I work with nodejs and socket I MODIFY code but suddenly the graph does not update ..
Here's the code :

Code client :

```
var chart;
var series = Array();
socket.on('ping', function(data){
    console.log(data);
      socket.emit('pong', {beat: 1})
    //console.log(i);   
requestData(data);      

    });
        function requestData(point) {
        if(point !== null){


                    //console.log('if'+point);
                    var series = chart.series[0],
                        shift = series.data.length > 60; // shift if the series is longer than 20
                    //alert(point);
                    chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

                    //setTimeout(requestData, 5000);    
        }
}

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                            zoomType: 'x',
                    backgroundColor: "#333333"
                },
                        load: function(){
                    chart = this;
                    requestData();
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Bitcoin price'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Bitcoin Price (Spot)',
                    data: []
                }]
            });     
        });
```

Code server :

```
var amount;
var dateN;
function updateChart(){
    setTimeout(updateChart, 5000);
    dateN =(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() /1000)*1000); // equal to time() in php
  client.getSpotPrice({'currency': 'USD'}, function(err, obj) {
        amount = obj.data.amount;
        });
    var info = [dateN,amount+phpjs.rand(01,99)];
    var pointd = JSON.stringify(info);
    console.log(pointd);
    //console.log(amount);
    pointd = phpjs.str_replace('"','',pointd);
    io.sockets.emit('ping', pointd);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('pong', function(data){
        console.log("Pong received from client");
    });
});
```

When I look at the log console I get well `[1446218389000,323.3578]` for example.
Exactly what I receive at the base with the script in php .

But not update the graph ..
If you have an idea ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Shift takes Boolean value , in your case the condition

```
shift = series.data.length > 60;
```

returning false ,as you may getting point data which may not >60. so instead use

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, true); //true in place of shift.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I settled my problem otherwise the coup ..
My script app.js I put in the database desired values ​​and client side ajax I made ​​a request to the server ordered by socket.io by to retrieve values ​​.